# gdb - refreshing display width and height when the host terminal resizes?

Tags: gdb

When gdb runs it sets its initial display size to that of the hosting terminal, ie so as to paginate after a screenful and to wrap lines on the right edge. After resizing the terminal I can manually reset these values, e.g.:

```
set width 140
set height 80
```

but this "read numbers in one place, type them into another" begs for automation. I had hoped that out-of-range values (set width -1) or commands like "refresh" would trigger a reset but I've yet to find anything.

If there is no in-built support then I (wildly) guess a python script could do this?

[EDIT: using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu on Mint(Mate) 16, no interesting customisations]

Comment: What OS are you on? Is this a custom gdb build or a downloaded one? Is your TERM environment variable set properly?

Comment: Sorry, that was neglectful of me! Mint(Mate) 16, standard gdb for the env (7.6.1-ubuntu), and TERM is just "xterm" (and I don't have any oddities with linewraps, etc, that might suggest it's generally confused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a gdb bug.  Please file it in gdb bugzilla, though beware that the TUI is under-maintained.

Comment: Oops, I see now that you didn't mention the TUI.  Still a bug; but this increases your chances of a fix :-)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy confirmation - raised as [bug 16762](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16762)